# How to be able to use session.open(false) in Apache IoTDB Version 1.0.0?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

When I tried to use `session.open(false)` API in Apache IoTDB, it can be used in Version 0.13, but cannot be used in Version 1.0.0. I wonder why this happen? And if I already updated my server to Version 1.0.0, what should I do to reactivate this API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the Apache IoTDB Version is 1.0, there is no `session.open(false)` API. Try to keep the session version and server version consistent. You can try to use Version 1.1 for both server and session.